# Button not works inside a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form, in this form I want to put some buttons, in case, submit and cancel.
I want this button stay in the same line, so I'm using a table.

But it's not working. 
When I put the cancel button inside this table, the button does not work and it is not redirecting to root_path.

But if I put the button(cancel) outside this table, the button works but does not stay on the same line with the submit button

Does not work:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h1><%= t('labels.analyst') %></h1></td>
    <td><%= f.submit :class => "btn"  %> </td>
    <td><%= button_to "Cancelar", root_path, :class => "btn", :method => :get %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Works:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h1><%= t('labels.analyst') %></h1></td>
    <td><%= f.submit :class => "btn"  %> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= button_to "Cancelar", root_path, :class => "btn", :method => :get %>
```

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
<%= link_to "Cancelar", root_path, :class => "btn" %>
```